# You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tbl_routines'

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

My code is to register an account by storing username and password into an access database. I get the error You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tbl_routines. From reading around I think it is because the value in my routine_id column of the main table is being left blank yet in tbl_routine there is no blank routine id as an option. In my program I am trying to register username and password first, and then later on in the program the user chooses a routine and it is stored in the table, but for now it needs to be left blank. I would assume that just adding a username and password into the table wouldn't affect the routine_id column since it is not listed as required, yet this error still pops up, and I don't know how to fix it.

```cs
if (txtRegPass.Text == txtRegPassConf.Text)
{
    con.Open();
    string register = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (username, [password]) VALUES ('" + txtRegUser.Text + "','" + txtRegPass.Text + "')"; 
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(register, con); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Account successfully created.", "Registration Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    txtRegUser.Text = "";
    txtRegPass.Text = "";
    txtRegPassConf.Text = ""; 
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match.", "Registration Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
    txtRegPass.Text = "";
    txtRegPassConf.Text = ""; 
}
```

Here is the image of the relationship in the database:

[image: tbl_routines 1 to ∞ tbl_users]

Comment: Can you create a default routine that you can assign to new users, when users try to do something with routines, you can check to which routine they are assigned.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Always.

Comment: @David.Warwick Don't know why this thought never occurred to me, doing this got it working, thanks!

Comment: @LarsTech Just read up about it, will change it to do so, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @cyro1_, glad you got it working. Please mark my suggestion as helpful.

Comment: @David.Warwick Sorry, I'm new to this website and I don't see the option to mark a comment as helpful, the option is only there for answers?

Comment: @cyro1_, Just click the Gray up arrow to the left of the comment.

Comment: @David.Warwick I don't know if I'm missing something but I really don't see anything except the flag https://imgur.com/a/qM4bqgo

Comment: It's ok. I up voted your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `routine_id` column as nullable in `tbl_users` table. In that case it won’t create this problem.

Comment: I went into design view on the table and don't see this as a property, unless you're referring to the 'Required' property, which is already set to No.